# Hosting mobile singalR App

Tags: jquery, cordova, signalr, hosting

I have a simple chat developed with SignalR. it works fine on local machine.

But I would like this to be used by a mobile phoneGap app (as clients). my questions are:

1. Since SingalR is a dotnet package/namespace/class,  do I need to upload the generated dll to the hosting provider ? or do I need something else to host this app?
2. Can this same browser app work once compiled within phoneGap for Android?
3. Can SignalR client work without jQuery ? since `$.connection` sounds like it is a jquery plugin

   ```
     var chat = $.connection.chatHub;//is this guy one of jquery plugins?
   ```

Comment: You asked 48 questions here, and accepted answers for only 4 of them. Please accept answers when it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you @Dialecticus : be sure, I do accept if It solve or help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosting has to comply with the list of supported platforms, even if you use a self hosted option the platform which the self-hosted server resides has to follow this list.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Supported server operating systems

The SignalR server component can be hosted in the following server or client operating systems. Note that for SignalR to use WebSockets, Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 is required (WebSocket can be used on Windows Azure Web Sites, as long as the site's .NET framework version is set to 4.5, and Web Sockets is enabled in the site's Configuration page).

```
Windows Server 2012
Windows Server 2008 r2
Windows 8
Windows 7
Windows Azure
```

If the hosting service uses IIS it should be version 8
Supported server IIS versions

When SignalR is hosted in IIS, the following versions are supported. Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being used. IIS Express should be used on client operating systems.

Also note that for SignalR to use WebSocket, IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express must be used, the server must be using Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, or later, and WebSocket must be enabled in IIS. For information on how to enable WebSocket in IIS, see IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support.

**Web browsers**
browser based client support must use **JQuery**. Using [WPF client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) would be a different story but I believe you are looking for a browser based approach.

SignalR can be used in a variety of web browsers, but typically, only the latest two versions are supported.

Applications that use SignalR in browsers must use **jQuery version 1.6.4** or major later versions (such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1).

SignalR can be used in the following browsers:

```
Microsoft Internet Explorer versions 8, 9, 10, and 11. Modern, Desktop, and Mobile versions are supported.
Mozilla Firefox: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
Google Chrome: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
Safari: current version - 1, both Mac and iOS versions.
Opera: current version - 1, Windows only.
Android browser
```